# How to place two LayoutDocuments side by side using AvalonDock

Tags: avalondock

I use avalondock LayoutDocumentPane like this:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager>
    <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        <avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Doc 1"/>
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Doc 2"/>
            </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
        </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
    </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

And this is what I got:

[image: Default layout]

However, I would like the layout to be like this:
[image: Layout I wanted]

How can I do that in XAML or C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just put them in separate panes, like this:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager>
    <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        <avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Doc 1"/>
            </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Doc 2"/>
            </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
        </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
    </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Comment: The panels do not collapse if you detach one of the panels for the first time. To avoid this you could put both `LayoutDocumentPane`s in a `LayoutDocumentPaneGroup`.